# Postgres : syntax error at or near "as"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, syntax-error, jooq

I am using JOOQ for java to postgresql db connection. It is trying to run this query.

```
insert into "public"."mission_batches" as "MB" 
  ("micro_task_id", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at") 
values 
  ('7e1cc9e8-fc11-409b-865e-3bf08e6ca924', false, timestamp '2016-10-05 21:47:13.061', timestamp '2016-10-05 21:47:13.061') returning "MB"."id", "MB"."micro_task_id", "MB"."is_active", "MB"."created_at", "MB"."updated_at"
```

But I am getting error from DB

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."mission_batches" as "MB" ("micro_task_id", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at") values (?, ?, cast(? as timestamp), cast(? as timestamp)) returning "MB"."id", "MB"."micro_task_id", "MB"."is_active", "MB"."created_at", "MB"."updated_at"];
ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
  Position: 40
```

It is working with my local DB[9.5]. On the test server [9.4], it is throwing this error. Where should I look for fix? Java side or PG side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliasing the table you're inserting into was only added in Postgres 9.5 (compare [Postgres 9.5's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) to [9.4's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html). Since the columns in the `returning` clause refer to the inserted table anyway, you could just as easily do without it:

```
insert into "public"."mission_batches"
  ("micro_task_id", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at") 
values 
  ('7e1cc9e8-fc11-409b-865e-3bf08e6ca924', false,
   timestamp '2016-10-05 21:47:13.061', timestamp '2016-10-05 21:47:13.061') 
returning 
  "id", "micro_task_id", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at"
```

Comment: So, only aliasing for insert is not supported in 9.4 ? Because this query is running perfectly

`select "U"."id", "U"."username", "E"."email" from "public"."users" as "U" join "public"."emails" as "E" on "U"."id" = "E"."user_id" where "E"."email" = 'abc@xyz.com'`

Comment: @theGamblerRises Yeah, aliasing in select has been there for a long time...

Comment: Oh,  ok. Then I'll change my code and make sure same version in all devices. Thanks